# How to turn the output of a function and pass it into a message widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been looking for answeres on this problem but came up with nothing so I might as well ask.So I am making this GUI with python and basically it's a little GUI that can find and add a customer to a csv file.
This is what I have now:

```
from tkinter import *
import csv

class guiVER1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #Name of the GUI
        self.master = master
        master.title("Packa-Parker's App")
        master.configure(bg="#ffffff")
        self.label = Label(master, text="Packa-Parker's Bank App")
        self.label.configure(bg='white')
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=4)

        myImage = PhotoImage(file ="C:/Users/Shay/Documents/Notebooks/LOGO Term 4.gif")
        self.ImageLabel = Label(master, image=myImage)
        self.ImageLabel.image = myImage
        self.ImageLabel.grid(row=6, column=5)

        self.master.geometry("400x400")

        # Where it stores the Client number
        self.label_text = StringVar()
        self.label_text.set("Find user?")
        self.label = Label(master, textvariable=self.label_text)
        self.label.grid(row=8, column=4)

        #Incase the user inputs something other than an integer/number
        self.label = Label(master, text="Please Type a Valid ID")

        #The number the GUI Starts with
        self.clientNumber= 0

        vcmd = master.register(self.validate)  # we have to wrap the command
        self.entry = Entry(master, validate="key", validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'))
        self.entry.grid(row=87, column=4)

        self.nameEntry = Entry(master, validate="key", validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'))
        self.nameEntry.grid(row=4, column=6)

        # The Button to run the find function
        self.updatebutton = Button(master, text="Find", command=self.userFinder)
        self.updatebutton.grid(row=7600, column=2)

        # The button to close the GUI
        self.closedbutton = Button(master, text='close', command=master.quit)
        self.closedbutton.grid(row=7605, column=2)

    def update(self):
        # Updates the number
        self.label_text.set(self.clientNumber)
        self.entry.delete(0,END)

    def updateName(self):
        self.label_text.set(self.nameEntry)
        self.entry.delete(0,END)

    def validate(self, newText):
        # Validate's the number
        if not newText:
            self.clientNumber = 0
            return True

        try:
            self.clientNumber = int(newText)
            print(self.clientNumber)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            print("Please type valid ID")
            return False

    def userFinder(self):
        # Finds the user using the client number
        # inputted by the user
        idx = str(self.clientNumber)
        with open("C:/Users/Shay/Documents/Notebooks/ITN/Assessment/ITN Term 4 Assessment Student Data.csv", 'r') as csvFile:
            csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
            data = list(csvFileReader)
            del data[:1]
            print(data)
            for d in data:
                if d[0] == idx:
                    print(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6], d[7])
                    break

root = Tk()
my_gui = guiVER1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

My problem is that I want the output of the userFinder function to appear in a separate window like a message widget or a text widget. Right now the userFinder function only outputs the information in the CLI but I want it to just open another window with all the information.

I am using python 3 and an IDE called Pycharm

Comment: What have you attempted so far to create the new window and push information to it?  Currently all `userFinder` does is print the information.

Comment: but the thing is what do i have to do to make it open a new window and print the same thing in the CLI to the new window?

Comment: You can display simple information using a [tkMessageBox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm). If you want something more elaborate, you could display the info in a [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) window.

Comment: How would I implement a tkMessageBox into that code

Answer (score 0):

You can call a basic `messagebox` by running something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

messagebox.showinfo("Title", "Content")

root.mainloop()
```

This means that in your code, I should imagine you'll simply need to import the `messagebox` and then substitute the below line . . .

```
print(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6], d[7])
```

. . . With something like this . . .

```
messagebox.showinfo("Title", (d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6], d[7]))
```

Comment: it just tells me messagebox undefined

Comment: Because as I said, *"you'll simply need to import the `messagebox`"*, you need to import `messagebox` before you can use it. Which I showed. In my example above. If you'd read it.

Comment: ID : 10008, Name: John, Lastname, Smith etc but make it go down a column

Comment: No, there isn't a way to format the box other than completely rewriting the widget, which is possible but a silly idea. Instead you can produce your own `Toplevel()` widget.